# PostgreSQL connection problems with R

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm having a bit of trouble when trying to connect to PostgreSQL on RStudio. I use `dbConnect` of the RPostgreSQL library and start filling up the other parts. The code I used is like this:

```
dbConnect("PostgreSQL", dbname = , host= , port = , user= , password = )
```

I already double checked all the info I wrote again and again, even tried changing the password because I thought the symbols on it were breaking the code.

I'm currently taking a pre-recorded course from 3 years ago, and I can't reach the teacher to ask about this. I tried to execute the code exactly as he did, but I get this error: «!ç)

I really want to solve this, as I want to finish the class, but I can't seem to comprehend it.

Edit: I tried updating both r and RStudio, as I saw a warning for the libraries, but the error only changed a bit into this: aŸ)

Answer (score 0):

You may have some success with this:

```
dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  driver = "PostgreSQL",
  dbname = ,
  server= ,
  port = ,
  uid= ,
  pwd =
)
```

Comment: Should I download anything else to make odbc work? Because now I'm getting the following:
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 01S00: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server inexistente ou acesso negado. [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Atributo de cadeia de conexão inválido

Comment: hmm, maybe try `DBI::dbConnect()` with the above code, rather than the RPostgreSQL library?

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully connect to a PostGres database in R with this chunk of code using `DBI::dbConnect`, as [langtang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4447540/langtang) suggested (after of course having loaded the credentials in my R session):

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
drv <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
DB <- DBI::dbConnect(drv, dbname = dbname, user = user, password = password, port = port, host= host)
```

Then the contents of your database should be queryable using `sf::st_read`.
Does this solve your issue?